# sharp corners after subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I have a mesh pattern with inside and outside corners...
in the inside corners one one layer, I am getting a sharp edge.
but the inside corners on the other layer are subdivided...
ive looked online...
is not the normals... all facing out...
is not unjoined mesh (ctrl+m)
ive fiddled with all the settings in the modifier and cant figure it out... my only conclusion is just a damaged mesh.

any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

figured it out...
forrest through the trees...

internal faces at the junctions...
but the next question is how to remove about a thousand of these faces...?
at the moment I am having to isolate each junction pull it up on edit mode, remove the faces, then repeat.

Comment: Hello :). Blender can select and delete internal faces. Get into Face select mode and go *Select > All by Trait > Interior Faces*

Comment: brilliant... thans a ton!